# Defining "DTD" with OpenAPI

Tags: dtd, openapi, openapi-generator

I want to define a schema and be able to generate stubs to parse it. I am looking into OpenAPI and Swagger Codegen. I wrote some time ago a test XSD and generated Java bindings for it. This schema is simply a number of POJOs. I know of other languages with other tools but it is not as extensive as Swagger Codegen.

I have used OpenAPI for other projects. For this case, I do not need to define the services, just the components. My idea is to have a schema for every future version and generate stubs from it.

I also considered SWIG but a C++ implementation would be required and it generates fewer languages. Besides, editing a YAML is more enticing than writing your own C++ implementation.

Any opinions on using OpenAPI just for the components? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The `paths` section is optional, so you can have an OpenAPI definition with just schemas.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: Components
  version: 1.0.0

paths: {}  # <--- No endpoint definitions

components:
  schemas:
    Schema1:
      ...
    Schema2:
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it validates.